# strtok() - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c, c-strings, string-parsing

I have written a small program for testing purposes. I expect it to output the following:

```
Geeks
for
Geeks;var1=d;key=value
```

See the code:

```
#include "header.h"

int fill_cmd_list(char *orig, char *token)
{
        token = strtok(orig, token);
        while (token != NULL) {
                printf("%s\n", token);
                token = strtok(NULL, token);
        }
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char *str,*trenner;
        trenner=malloc(sizeof(char)*2);
        strcpy(trenner,"-");
        str = malloc(sizeof(char)*1000);
        strcpy(str,"Geeks-for-Geeks;var1=d;key=value");
        fill_cmd_list(str,trenner);

        return;
}
```

It compiles fine but the output is:

```
Geeks
for-
eeks;va
1=d
key
valu
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I mixed up the function parameters and should not have assigned to the token itself.

Here's the code running fine as expected:

```
#include "header.h"


int fill_cmd_list(char *orig, char *trenner)
{
        char *token;
        token = strtok(orig, trenner);
        while (token != NULL) {
                printf("%s\n", token);
                token = strtok(NULL, trenner);
        }
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char *str,*trenner;
        trenner=malloc(sizeof(char)*2);
        strcpy(trenner,"-");
        str = malloc(sizeof(char)*1000);
        strcpy(str,"Geeks-for-Geeks;var1=d;key=value");
        fill_cmd_list(str,trenner);

        return;
}
```

Comment: You do not need the `trenner` variable, `fill_cmd_list(str, "-");` will work just fine. And while not standard, most system have the `strdup` function that does the `malloc` and `strcpy` for you. So `str =strdup("Geeks-.....");`